# Android studio, Linux, не может запустить avd

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, avd

Устройство создал без ошибок, но вот запустить не могу.

Останавливается на:
Waiting for target device to common online. После чего благополучно ничего не происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Логи]

Comment: Мой режим телепатии работает плохо, потому рекомендую, как и всегда, приложить логи, запустить эмулятор из консоли с опциями отображения отладки или просто подробностей запуска. В графических приложениях, как правило, можно включить режим отображения подробностей, но эта опция где-то в глубине настроек - поэтому проще запустить приложение из консоли. И дальше, основываясь на логах, уже можно что-то думать. От себя же могу сказать, что все известные мне эмуляторы андроида - это конечно лучше, чем совсем ничего, но в реальности, когда нужно работать, лучше использовать реальное устройство.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, может быть выключена поддержка виртуализации (в настройках материнской платы, про проверку - см. http://igorka.com.ua/2010-07-06/proverka-podderzhki-processorom-apparatnoj-virtualizacii/).

Comment: @bukkojot надеюсь, я понял вас правильно. Отредактировал пост.

Comment: Еще нашел такой момент.
В /root/Android/Sdk/tools лежит 2 исполняемых файла: android и emulator. Проверяю список avd с помощью
./android list avd - получаю имя устройства, потом через 
./emulator -avd name_avd пытаюсь запустить. Но происходит ошибка, такого устройства нет

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, разобрался. 
По пути /root/Android/Sdk/tools лежат два исполняемых файла: emulator и android. 2-ой почему-то видит устройства, а 1-ый нет, потому что пытается их найти по пути /home/*user*/.android/avd (или $HOME/.android/avd). 
Шаги решения:

1. apt install gksudo (так будет проще)
2. Открыть с помощью этой утилиты свой файловый менеджер.
   (Например: gksudo nautilus)
3. Перемещаем папку Android и .android по пути %HOME
4. Замена Sdk пути в настройках Android studio.

P.S. Остается одна проблема. При создании виртуального устройства каждый раз придется его перемещать. Для этого нужно создавать системную переменную. Как разберусь с этим вопрос в другой теме - сброшу ссылку.